# Not using a correct syntax to call function in main

Tags: haskell

I'm figuring out Haskell and I am trying to make a simple game. Still I do not understand how to work with the `Main.hs`

This is what I want to do:

### in Main.hs

```
module Main where

import System.IO

main :: IO()
main =  do
    result <- charName 'a' -- error could not match type
    putStr result -- error could not match type

charName :: Char -> String
charName 'a' = "Albert"
charName 'b' = "Broseph"
charName 'c' = "Cecil"
```

With the function `charName` I want to pass the Char 'a' as a parameter so the main function can print out `Albert`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the `var <- computation` syntax is for monadic values (inside a `do` block) like `getLine`.

In your case you have a pure computation so you can use `let` just like you would do in GHCi:

```
main :: IO()
main =  do
    let result = charName 'a`
    putStr result
```